# Can't modify circle once added to map

Tags: android

I've added a circle to my map. The method that removes the circle is called for a separate thread, this is what I've tried so far. I've tried quite a few other ways but no joy modifying it.

```
Circle myCircle;

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {   
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                removeCircle();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 0);

public void removeCircle(){

    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            myCircle.remove();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error, I just can't remove the circle. Its become an immutable object!

Comment: Why don't you put a `log` in `removeCircle()` and see if it is being called or not?

Comment: I put toast in there, its certainly being called.

Comment: I don't see your circle being initialized.

Comment: I presume you're using the `new Handler()` to have something run on the main/UI thread. However, from the code snippet, we cannot be sure that this `Handler` will relate to the main/UI thread. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I'm using the new Handler just a 1 second timer to repeatedly do something. What is a sure fire way to make sure it is being called on the UI thread?

Comment: Does the code work if you run it in single threaded mode somehow?